# How to use Func with IQueryable that returns IOrderedQueryable

Tags: linq

I'm doing some research about EF and came across a function that accepts

```
Func<IQueryable<Student>, IOrderedQueryable<Student>>
```

and just wondering how to call that function that accepts that kind of parameter?

Comment: Want to tell us which function, to make it easier to explain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

imagine function is something like that, and you've got a property Id in Student class.

```
public static class Helper {
    public static void Test(Func<IQueryable<Student>, IOrderedQueryable<Student>> param)
        {
            var test = 0;
        }
}
```

then you could use it this way

```
var student = new List<Student>().AsQueryable();//non sense, just for example
Helper.Test(m => student.OrderBy(x => x.Id));
```

`m => student.OrderBy(x => x.Id)` is a

```
Func<IQueryable<Student>, IOrderedQueryable<Student>>
```

(`IQueryable<student>` as parameter, returning a `IOrderedQueryable<Student>`)

or just

```
Helper.Test(m => m.OrderBy(x => x.Id));
```

In fact this doesn't make much sense without a "real" function...

Answer (score 4):

define a method.

```
public IOrderedQueryable<Student> OrderingMethod(IQueryable<Student> query)
{
  return query.OrderBy(student => student.Name);
}
```

Now this assignment is legal:

```
Func<IQueryable<Student>, IOrderedQueryable<Student>> orderingFunc = this.OrderingMethod;
```

And now that you have it in a variable, it's easy to pass it to the method.

---

You could also do it all inline:

```
Func<IQueryable<Student>, IOrderedQueryable<Student>> orderingFunc =
  query => query.OrderBy(student => student.Name);
```