# EF Generic Repository Multiple Includes and OrderBy Call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern

I have reviewed many examples of EF Generic Repository.I couldn't find an instance of `OrderBy` and `Include`.I have no idea how to fill in question points in controller `(orderBy:?,includes:?)`.I stuck here.I'm waiting for your help

**Repository**

```
public List<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
        E_ComDBContext db = new E_ComDBContext();
        DbSet<T> dbSet;
        dbSet = db.Set<T>();

        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
            query = query.Include(include);

        //if (select != null)
        //    query = query.Select(select);
        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        if (orderBy != null)
            query = orderBy(query);

        return query.ToList();
}
```

**Contoller**

```
public JsonResult List()
{
    Repository<Product> _repository = new Repository<Product>();          
    var list = _repository.Get(x=>x.Price>10,orderBy:?,includes:?);           
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775658/how-to-use-func-with-iqueryable-that-returns-iorderedqueryable

Comment: Why even write a get method like that.  If you are using a generic repository, why not make the a GetAll method that just returns the IQueryable and the the developer just tack on his own ordeby includes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would give this a try.

```
var list = _repository.Get(filter: x => x.Price > 10, orderBy: x=> x.OrderBy(y => y.Price), x => x.Location, x=> x.Brand);
```